# Problems with encrypting a file

Tags: c, file, security, encryption

I was trying to encrypt a file from a header file and every time I run the program, it deletes the information in the file AccountInformation.txt. Is there any reason why it is deleting the information from AccountInformation.txt and how can I fix my code?

Any help will be great, thank you.

The c code is bellow:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "Encryption1.h"


// Variable for signup and login
char fname[120], lname[120], username[120], password[120]; 
int session;
FILE * accountInfoPointer;
// Main Fucntion for sign up and login

int main (void)
{
  // Asking user is they want to sign up or login
  printf("What would you like to do?\n");
  printf("1. Sign u\n");
  printf("2. Login\n"); 
  printf("3. Admin login");
  scanf("%d", &session);
  
  // signup
  switch(session)
  {
    case 1:
      // Retreiving all of the user's data 
      
      printf("What is your FIRST name?\n");
      scanf(" %s", fname);

      printf("What is your LAST name?\n");
      scanf(" %s", lname);

      printf("Please enter a username?\n");
      scanf(" %s", username);

      printf("Create a password\n");
      scanf(" %s", password);

              accountInfoPointer = fopen("AccountInformation.txt", "a");
              
              fprintf(accountInfoPointer, "Name: %s %s\nUsername: %s\nPassword: %s\n\n", fname, lname, username, password);
              
              fclose(accountInfoPointer); 
     
     
      goto Encrypt; //goes to calender menu 

    Encrypt:{ 
    //char Title;{ 
   printf("\n\n\t\t\t\t::::::Encrypt::::::\n");  
 encrypted1(1);       
 
    } 
 break;      


     
  }
  }
```

This is the header file code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
 
int encrypt(void);
int decrypt(void);
int encrypt_view(void);
int decrypt_view(void);
 
FILE *fp1, *fp2;
char ch;
 
void encrypted1(int Encrypt)
{
    int choice;
    while(1)
    {   
        printf("Select One of the Following:\n");
        printf("\n1. Encrypt\n");   
        printf("2. Decrypt\n");
        printf("3. View The Encypted File\n");
        printf("4. View The Decrypted File\n");
        printf("5. Exit\n");
        printf("\nEnter Your Choice:\t");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1: encrypt();
                break;
            case 2: decrypt();
                break;
            case 3: encrypt_view();
                break;
            case 4: decrypt_view();
                break;
            case 5: exit(1);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
   // return 0;
}
 
int encrypt()
{
    printf("\n");
    fp1 = fopen("AccountInformation.txt","r");
    if(fp1 == NULL)
    {
        printf("Source File Could Not Be Found\n");
    }
    fp2 = fopen("AccountInformation.txt","w");
    if(fp2 == NULL)
    {
        printf("Target File Could Not Be Found\n");
    }
    while(1)
    {
        ch = fgetc(fp1);
        if(ch == EOF)
        {
            printf("\nEnd Of File\n");
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            ch = ch - (8 * 5 - 3);
            fputc(ch, fp2);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp1);
    fclose(fp2);
    printf("\n");
    //return 0;
}
 
int decrypt()
{
    printf("\n");
    fp1 = fopen("AccountInformation.txt","r");
    if(fp1 == NULL)
    {
        printf("Source File Could Not Be Found\n");
    }
    fp2 = fopen("AccountInformation.txt","w");
    if(fp2 == NULL)
    {
        printf("Target File Could Not Be Found\n");
    }
    while(1)
    {
        ch = fgetc(fp1);
        if(ch == EOF)
        {
            printf("\nEnd Of File\n");
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            ch = ch + (8 * 5 - 3);
            fputc(ch, fp2);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp1);
    fclose(fp2);
    printf("\n");
    //return 0;
}
 
int encrypt_view()
{
    printf("\n");
    fp1 = fopen("AccountInformation.txt","r");
    if(fp1 == NULL)
    {
        printf("No File Found\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        while(1)
        {
            ch = fgetc(fp1);
            if(ch == EOF)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%c", ch);
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
        fclose(fp1);
    }
    printf("\n");
    //return 0;
}
 
int decrypt_view()
{
    printf("\n");
    fp1 = fopen("AccountInformation.txt","r");
    if(fp1 == NULL)
    {
        printf("No File Found\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        while(1)
        {
            ch = fgetc(fp1);
            if(ch == EOF)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%c", ch);
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
        fclose(fp1);
    }
   // return 0;
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Hint: the problem is here: `fopen("AccountInformation.txt","w");`

Comment: I change 'w' to 'r', 'a' and 'a+', but it's still deleting the information.

Answer (score 0):

```
fp1 = fopen("AccountInformation.txt","r");
if(fp1 == NULL)
{
    printf("Source File Could Not Be Found\n");
}
fp2 = fopen("AccountInformation.txt","w");
if(fp2 == NULL)
{
    printf("Target File Could Not Be Found\n");
}
```

I cringe at this, but the idea should work on unix derivatives. You're clobbering your data because you should have used "r+" but you used "w". The `+` turns on both read and write, but `w+` is going to truncate. You don't want `a`. Unless you're writing a log file, you don't want `a` so don't try it here.

Comment: I'm sorry you cringe at this lol, still new to C programming. But I have used r+ but it just deletes the information in the txt file

Comment: @GamerGirl: The normal approach is to only decrypt in RAM and only store encrypted on disk.

Answer (score 0):

At least this problem:

**Unable to distinguish all input from `fgetc()` properly**

`char`, as 8-bit, can encode 256 combinations. `int fgetc()` returns 257 values: `[0-UCHAR_MAX]` and `EOF`.

Code encrypts with `ch = ch - (8 * 5 - 3);  fputc(ch, fp2);` which easily generates a `char` that collides with `EOF` on a later read making the file scant.

```
char ch;  // Bad
ch = fgetc(fp1);
if(ch == EOF)  // Was ch an EOF or some character?
```

Use `int ch` to distinguish the return values from `fgetc()`.

---

For *encryption/decryption*, better to open the files in *binary* mode than *text* mode.  Append a `"b"`.

```
// fp1 = fopen("AccountInformation.txt","r");
fp1 = fopen("AccountInformation.txt","rb");
```

---

Alternative sample code:

```
int encrypt_view(void) {
  printf("\n");
  FILE *fp = fopen("AccountInformation.txt", "rb");
  if (fp == NULL) {
    printf("No File Found\n");
    return 1; // Let calling code exit
  }

  int ch;
  while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
    if (ch >= ' ' && ch <= '~') {
      printf("%c", ch);
    } else {
      printf("<%d>", ch);
    }
  }
  printf("\n");
  fclose(fp);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me with the encrypt_view, I kinda understand what I have to do to encrypt my code.

Comment: So I was coding and using the example you gave me (Thank you) to trying to code my encryption but I have been getting a 'double free or corruption (out)' when I run my code when I try to encrypt my file. ` 
       if ((ch = fgetc(fp1) != EOF)) {
         ch = ch+3; 
      printf("%c", ch);
    } `